# Google change of address: from (site1.example and site2.example) to (newsite.example/1 and newsite.example/2)

Tags: google-search-console, url, search, migration

I'm trying to tell Google that I'm merging two sites into one, with the following URLs:

- `site1.example` to `newsite.example/1`
- `site2.example` to `newsite.example/2`

I already set 301s to the relevant pages of `newsite.example` from `site1.example` and `site2.example`.

Problem: Google Search Console's change of address tool only sees `newsite.example` as a proper destination, I cannot properly set my redirections there. I thought about the following workaround:

1. Create the subdomain `1.newsite.example` and redirect to `newsite.example/1`
2. register `1.newsite.example` in Google Search Console and register change of address from `site1.example` to `newsite.example/1`

Is this risky? Is there an alternative?

Comment: Do not work around this. The change of address is to point one domain to another. Completely unnecessary. Your 301 redirects should be enough. When you are satisfied that the new site has been properly indexed and if there are no valuable links, you can delete the old domains. Otherwise, the 301 redirects can remain. Do build links to the new site though.

Comment: @closetnoc this should be the answer here.

Comment: Create additional Search Console properties for newsite.com/1 and newsite.com/2, so you can exactly monitor the ranking shift.

Answer (score 1):

If the content is going to be the same as the two older sites maybe consider adding a canonical meta tag to your head section of your code. The 301 redirects should be enough for Google but the canonical tag MAY reduce any duplicate content issues at the same time